# Like variable substitution but on the result of an command in bash

Tags: bash

I can do this

```
datestr=$(date)
echo "${datestr// /_}"
```

prints date where all spaces are replaced with `_`

```
Fri_Sep__5_21:56:05_CEST_2014
```

Is it possible to do somewhat without the helper variable? something such

```
echo ${$(date)// /_}  #this of course didn't works
```

I know, it is possible to do with e.g. `echo $(date | tr ' ' '_')`, but this runs another process and i looking for a pure bash.

Comment: A few commands provide a way to format its output: `date +"%a_%b__%d_%H:%M:%S_%Z_%Y"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. The first operand of a parameter expansion operation cannot be another expansion nor a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea. Create a function

```
x() { echo "${@// /_}"; }
```

and enter

```
x $(date)
```

Without a helper variable, no onother process and pure bash.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but instead of the helper variable, need a helper function :) ;) thanx anyway. ;)